# Trying to perform bitwise operation on a negative number to make 0s in bits 31-16 (32 bit number) in C

Tags: c, bit-shift, twos-complement

I have a number, -3, that I would like to use as a 16 bit integer and use an | (or) operator with a 32 bit integer.
So ideally, I need it so that -3, in binary two's complement, will be 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1101
I've tried bit wise operation using

```
int x = -3;
x = x << 16;
x = x >> 16;
```

I thought this would ideally put 0's in the bits 31-16 (0 indexed), but it doesn't seem to work. Any help to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a must to use shift? Can also use bit mask: `x = x & 0x0000ffff;`

Comment: If you wanted 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1101, why did you not just use `0xFFFD`?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to get the two’s complement of 3 in 16 bits, with higher bits clear, are:

- Include `<stdint.h>` and use `(uint16_t) -3`.
- Use `-3u & 0xffffu`.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting a negative value to the left is *undefined behavior*.

```
int x = -3;
x = x << 16; // UB!
```

Shifting a negative value to the right is *implementation-defined behavior*.

---

Best to use *unsigned* type (or small postive values) when shifting.

---

> to perform bitwise operation on a negative number to make 0s in bits 31-16 (32 bit number) i

Use `&` to mask and retain only the least significant 16 bits.

```
int32_t x = -3;
x &= 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: so would there be a way to just get the values of the last 16 bits in the binary number 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1101 without using shifting? because i need to work with this negative number

Comment: I am confused, you say shifting to the right is `UB`, this is shifting to the left `x = x << 16; // UB!` that should not be UB iirc

Comment: @KPCT Answer does not say "shifting to the right is UB".  It does have "Shifting a negative value to the left is undefined behavior" and "Shifting a negative value to the right is implementation-defined behavior."

Comment: Ah found this https://newbedev.com/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-operand-has-negative-value I see now, it's dependent if it is 2s complement or 1s.

Comment: @KPCT Not quite. It is UB/IDB as described above even if  2s complement or 1s.  Even with 2's, a compiler may optimze in ways you do not expect with UB.  Simply, don't code that way.